# Classification of associative polynomial functions

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, semigroups-and-monoids, fields

What is known about a classification of associative (binary)  polynomial functions? First of all, it is interesting in two cases: over Integral domain (or even over field) and over ring of integers modulo $n$.

(A polynomial binary function is function $R \times R \to R$  induced by a polynomial in two variables $P$ over a ring $R$.)

Comment: If you find an associative polynomial P(x,y) where the term Q(x,y) = P(x,P(y,x)) is also associative, then the structure with underlying set R and binary operation P generates a locally finite variety; further, you just have to check three more terms in P to see if they and all other terms in P are associative.  In case you needed lots of associative polynomials.  Gerhard "Search On Hyperassociativity In MathOverflow" Paseman, 2020.01.25.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over an infinite integral domain you can classify all polynomials that satisfy the associativity functional equation. A quick degree consideration of both sides tells you that the polynomial is at most degree $1$ in each variable, so the only answers are $x,y, c+x+y$ and $c_1(x+c_2)(y+c_2)-c_2$. In fact you can classify all $n$-variable polynomials which satisfy the $n$-ary version of associativity, as done in the paper ["A description of n-ary semigroups polynomial-derived from integral domains"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.6291v2).

As far as finite rings, I doubt you can say anything meaningful. For example, already over $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, any binary function can be written as a polynomial map, so you would be asking for a classification of all associative operations on this set (this number increases [very fast](https://oeis.org/A023814)).

Comment: Many thanks !

(Note: in your answer there are no polynomials x and y)